# Is there any other reason besides readability to use elsif versus nested if in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I was learning Transact-SQL, which doesn't have an elsif equivalent and only has a pseudo-structure, else if, which is in reality a nested if...else.  I've been a PL/SQL programmer for roughly 8 years so I had been using if...elsif...else for sometime without really giving it much thought.  I know elsif keeps the execution within a single logical block versus a series of nested blocks, but is there a reason aside from readability for using elsif versus nested if's?  Essentially, is there an efficiency gain or some other benefit to keeping them in a single logical block?

For example I could do this:

```
if x = 1 then
    dbms_output.put_line('foo');
elsif x=3 then
    dbms_output.put_line('foo2');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('foo3');
end if;
```

Or I could do this:

```
if x=1 then
    dbms_output.put_line('foo1');
else 
     if x=3 then
         dbms_output.put_line('foo2');
     else
         dbms_output.put_line('foo3');
     end if;
end if;
```

I know PL/SQL best practices suggest using the first example, but I was curious if there was a reason for it aside from the extraneous "end if;" and the messy indents when you get past 2 or 3 levels deep.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: You can look into your code.WhIch one do you find less shabby and readable. ;)

Comment: Disregarding readability, the purpose itself is different. In your case they seem redundant, but not actually. It not just applies to PL/SQL.. IF-ELSIF is very much like SWITCH.. only one will be executed at a time. Where-as Nested IFs gives you flexibility to give multiple conditional check. So choose what favours you! It is like Choosing For/While Loop!

Answer (score 1):

I read Oracle's style guide more carefully and noted that Oracle does say that they are the same in terms of how they are executed and what performance to expect.  So aside from logically linking the conditionals together with the If...elsif...else versus discrete conditional statements, there is no benefit in terms of Oracle's execution of the statements.  I appreciate all of the replies on this.